# How to set-up UTC time in w2k8?

Tags: windows-server-2008, utc

I am searching to set the clock of w2k8 in UTC, in w2k3 you could choose the Coordinated  Universal time in the option of the clock. (you can still in Vista)
Now in w2k8 there is only GMT timezone and no trace of the Coordinated Universal Time a s a choice.

Anyone knows how to do it ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTC and GMT are basically the same thing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: However Windows' time zone "(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London" is not the same as "(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time" during the summertime. Also see this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292334/difference-between-utc-and-gmt-standard-time-in-net).

Answer (score 3):

Applying a Cumulative Time Zone Update will create UTC as an option on Vista/2008 systems.  The latest one (as of this answer) is at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2633952.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, what GUIs like Windows call GMT can change for summer time (daylight savings time).  If you're setting the time using the GUI and you want UTC, you can choose a city like Timbuktu in Africa which is in UTC+0 and doesn't have daylight savings time.

If you are using the command line, you can do:

```
tzutil.exe /s "GMT Standard Time"_dstoff
```

That will be UTC+0 with no DST shifts.

Comment: Holy Crap - Timbuktu is a *real place*?